# Can i add Navigationdrawer to an existing Android project?

Tags: android

I have started Android project.Now(in middle of the project) i got new requirement to add Navigation drawer.is it possible to add now?. I tried to change the main_activity.xml . it's not working.....

Comment: Yes, it's possible, answering your question is not

Comment: It's possible but changing the main_activity.xml is not enough, you need to code the behaviour of your navigation drawer

Comment: Why not !! you have to do extra things to integrate it. But yes you can add Navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio automatically creates a NavigationDrawer Activity for you.  Right-click and highlight the option to create a new activity.  This will display the various types of activities you can use.  Select NavigationDrawer Activity and the mainActivity, navDrawerFragment, activity_main.xml, and navdrawer.xml files will be created for you.